# C# MVC 5 Getting issue with date

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am getting issue with date field  only with one machine. Date is not displaying in the field.

Below is code written for date field

```
     [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select birthdate")]
         [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
         [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public string BirthDate { get; set; }
```

View File -

```
 @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BirthDate, new { @class = "hiddenEmployee col-sm-3 label-form" })
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BirthDate, new { @class = "DOB form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.BirthDate)
            </div>

    JS code to bind datepicker to field is as follows-
       $('.DOB').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: '-100:+100',
            buttonImage: "../../Content/images/calender-icon.png",
            showOn: "both",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            autoclose: true,
            buttonImageText: "Calendar",
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            todayHighlight: true
        }).on('change', function () {
            try {
                $(this).valid();  // triggers the validation test
            }
            catch (e)
            { }       
        });;
```

This issue is getting only with one server for others working fine also with Local machine too.

Comment: Does the culture of that server accept dates in the format `dd/MM/yyyy` and have you set the culture in the `web.config.cs` file?

Comment: Is that "date is not displaying" means "date value doesn't display inside datepicker" or "datepicker element is not rendered on browser"? If it's going for first meaning, try examining culture-related date formatting and server config, otherwise check your HTML output or console.

Comment: Is it the same data on all machines or is the one not displaying the text accessing some other datasource where the date could be missing?